# Compare two data frames based on common columns

Tags: r

I have two csv files:

file1:

```
SN  CY  Year    Month   Day Hour    Lat Lon
196101  1   1961    1   14  12  8.3 134.7
196101  1   1961    1   14  18  8.8 133.4
196101  1   1961    1   15  0   9.1 132.5
196101  1   1961    1   15  6   9.3 132.2
196101  1   1961    1   15  12  9.5 132
196101  1   1961    1   15  18  9.9 131.8
```

file2:

```
Year    Month Day RR Hour Lat  Lon
1961    1   14  0   0   14.0917 121.055
1961    1   14  0   6   14.0917 121.055
1961    1   14  0   12  14.0917 121.055
1961    1   14  0   18  14.0917 121.055
1961    1   15  0   0   14.0917 121.055
1961    1   15  0   6   14.0917 121.055
```

I want to add another column in file2 and put "TRUE" if the rows in file2 are present in file1 whenever they have the same Year,Month,Day, and Hour otherwise "FALSE". Then save as a csv file.

The desired output:

```
Year    Month Day RR Hour Lat  Lon      com
1961    1   14  0   0   14.0917 121.055 FALSE
1961    1   14  0   6   14.0917 121.055 FALSE
1961    1   14  0   12  14.0917 121.055 TRUE
1961    1   14  0   18  14.0917 121.055 TRUE
1961    1   15  0   0   14.0917 121.055 TRUE
1961    1   15  0   6   14.0917 121.055 TRUE
```

Here's my script:

```
jtwc <- read.csv("file1.csv",header=T,sep=",")
stn <- read.csv("file2.csv",header=T,sep=",")

if ((jtwc$Year == "stn$YY") & (jtwc$Month == "stn$MM") & (jtwc$Day == "stn$DD") &(jtwc$Hour == "stn$HH")){
stn$com <- "TRUE"
} else {
stn$com <- "FALSE"
}
write.csv(stn,file="test.csv",row.names=T)
```

This gives an error:

```
In if ((jtwc$Year == "stn$YY") & (jtwc$Month == "stn$MM") & (jtwc$Day ==  :the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: make a reproducible example. like post result head(dput(YOURDATA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution using [**`data.table`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2):

1. Use `fread` to read in files.
2. Extract wanted columns from `file1` (as you're only interested in `file2`)
3. Merge files using `merge`
4. If there was no match from `file1` add `FALSE`

Code:

```
library(data.table)
result <- merge(fread("file2.csv"),
                fread("file1.csv")[, .(Year, Month, Day, Hour, com = TRUE)], 
                all.x = TRUE)[is.na(com), com := FALSE]

result
   Year Month Day Hour RR     Lat     Lon   com
1: 1961     1  14    0  0 14.0917 121.055 FALSE
2: 1961     1  14    6  0 14.0917 121.055 FALSE
3: 1961     1  14   12  0 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
4: 1961     1  14   18  0 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
5: 1961     1  15    0  0 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
6: 1961     1  15    6  0 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use dplyr/tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
d2 %>% 
  left_join(select(d1, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Com=Lon)) %>% 
  mutate(Com=ifelse(is.na(Com), FALSE, TRUE))

Joining, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour")
  Year Month Day RR Hour     Lat     Lon   Com
1 1961     1  14  0    0 14.0917 121.055 FALSE
2 1961     1  14  0    6 14.0917 121.055 FALSE
3 1961     1  14  0   12 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
4 1961     1  14  0   18 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
5 1961     1  15  0    0 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
6 1961     1  15  0    6 14.0917 121.055  TRUE
```